# Arithmetic that corresponds to combinatorial rectangles and cylinder intersections?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lo.logic, computational-complexity, discrete-geometry, big-picture

Definable subsets of $\mathbb N$ in the language of Presburger arithmetic are exactly the eventually periodic sets.

In communication complexity the interpretation is more on intersection and union of combinatorial rectangles or complements of combinatorial cylinder intersections which does not seem to be as nice as what comes from geometric interpretation of Presburger.

Is there an arithmetic that corresponds to definable sets in communication complexity?

Would it be reasonable to expect something?